# NoClassDefFoundError appears only on one Computer

Tags: java, maven, robotframework, noclassdeffounderror

I am new to stackoverflow and full of hope that anybody has a hint for me what is wrong with my computer or settings.

I am trying to run a robot-framework-project on my computer which was developed on by an colleague to make it compatible with jrobotremoteserver.
It runs on his machine without any problems. Also it runs on the machine of another colleague, again without problems.
But when I try to run it on my computer (after Building) I get an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: distinct.rpc.Auth
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:481)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:1110)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:898)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:806)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:764)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1086)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: distinct.rpc.Auth
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:766)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1086)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    ... 15 more
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:881)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:841)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:447)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

There is a class in my dependencies, which IS found. And it refers to a class in the same dependency-jar, which is NOT found.

Strange thing is: I have the same settings.xml as my colleague. I use the same repositories.
I use the same JDKs. Same IntelliJ-Version by now and bundled Maven Version.
But still the error occurs.

Sadly I am not allowed to share any code and due to the special form of this error, it is not possible to create a minimal example.

Nobody of my team has a clue. I even deinstalled and installed the project several times and even deleted it from my computer and checked out again from svn.
I deleted the complete local repository and therefore forced a new update.

I debugged and it is really what I wrote above:
One class from dependency-jar was found, next was not.

I spent a long time to google the issue, but no described problem meets my situation.
Anyway, is there any chance that somebody else ran into the same problem once and found the solution?

Greetings
Britta